# Exporting the SSRS Report in pdf format is having blank page issues

Tags: sql, reporting-services, export, ssrs-tablix

In SSRS Report 2016, I have 2 tablixes. The 2nd tablix contains only 4 columns.

When I preview the report, It comes perfectly in one page but when I export the report in PDF format or click on the Print Layout button in the report, the whole 2nd table/tablix moves to the next page.

In my case, the sum `(Body Width + Left margin + Right margin)` is less than the resulting page width. I set `keep_together` property to `false` but the 2nd table keeps rendering on the new page. If the 2nd table has less content then it displays below the first table on the same page and if the content is a little bit large then the whole table shifted to the next page and if the content is too big then it starts displays on the 1st page below the first table on the same page and continues on next pages with the remaining content. All the thing is happening when I am exporting report in PDF format, not on report preview.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have dynamic col grouping or hidden textboxes ? in this case you need to make sure that when all the col visible on the reports it must have sum of width and margins less than the reports width.
2. Cross check the report width from properties window sometimes it contains white spaces because of which this happens.
3. Check whether you have added a page break after the tablix. If you did, and if there is nothing else to show after the tablix, then it will display blank on the next page.

Another possible reason that may bring blank page is that there exists large white space between tablix and page footer.

Please try these points once. Hope it resolve your issue.

Comment: I cross-checked all your mentioned points, all the thing is balanced but still facing the same issue.